# Closing Word app, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

i am trying to search within word documents, using vb.net it worked but i cant seem to close the files after searching them, here is the code i use
how to close the word apps after being searched ?

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application = Nothing
    Dim oDocs As Word.Documents = Nothing
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document = Nothing
    Dim folderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = True
    If (folderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder
    End If
    Dim l_Dir As IO.DirectoryInfo
    Dim fldpath As String = folderDlg.SelectedPath
    If IO.Directory.Exists(fldpath) Then
        l_Dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo(fldpath)

        For Each l_File In Directory.GetFiles(fldpath, "*.docx")


            Dim searchFor As String = TextBox1.Text


            oWord = New Word.Application()
            oWord.Visible = False

            oDocs = oWord.Documents
            oDoc = oDocs.Open(l_File, False)
            oDoc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting()

            Dim findText As String = searchFor

            Try
                If oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(findText) = True Then
                    MessageBox.Show("OK.")

                    oWord.NormalTemplate.Saved = True
                    oWord.ActiveDocument.Close(False)
                    oDoc.Close()
                    oWord.Quit()

                    If Not oDoc Is Nothing Then
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDoc)
                        oDoc = Nothing
                    End If
                    If Not oDocs Is Nothing Then
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDocs)
                        oDocs = Nothing
                    End If
                    If Not oWord Is Nothing Then
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWord)
                        oWord = Nothing
                    End If

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("No.")
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(l_File)
        Next

    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should bear in mind is that "releasing the objects" in Word is not as difficult as in Excel and thus you are (unnecessarily) over-complicating things. In any case, you should intend to not over-declare variables (what is the exact point of `oDocs`?). And, lastly, you should always perform a step-by-step execution when things go wrong to find out what might be happening (you are applying your "objects release" only for "OK" cases, not in any situation: when the result is "No", the objects would have to be released too).

Here you have a corrected code accounting for all the aforementioned issues:

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application = Nothing
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = Nothing
Dim folderDlg As New FolderBrowserDialog
folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = True
If (folderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
    Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder
End If
Dim l_Dir As IO.DirectoryInfo
Dim fldpath As String = folderDlg.SelectedPath
If IO.Directory.Exists(fldpath) Then
    l_Dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo(fldpath)

    For Each l_File In Directory.GetFiles(fldpath, "*.docx")

        Dim searchFor As String = TextBox1.Text

        oWord = New Word.Application()
        oWord.Visible = False

        Try
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(l_File, False)
            oDoc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting()

            Dim findText As String = searchFor

            Try
                If oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(findText) = True Then
                    MessageBox.Show("OK.")

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("No.")
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            oWord.NormalTemplate.Saved = True

            ComboBox1.Items.Add(l_File)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        oDoc = Nothing
        oWord.Quit()
        oWord = Nothing

    Next

End If
```

NOTE: note that, when iterating through all the Word files in a folder (and, in general, ones from any MS Office program), you can find temporary copies (starting with "~$...") which might trigger an error when being opened (and thus not allow the object-releasing part to come into picture); also, in general, when opening files something might go wrong; this is what explains the new try...catch I added and why I put the releasing part after it.

Comment: Thank you still i have winword processes running and normal.dot save appears after searching the files

Comment: @user2652374 press ctrl+alt+sup, kill all the running Winword instances, execute this code and everything will be fine (= no Winword instance will be running after closing this application).

Comment: i did this i still have a msg for normal.dot and a winword process running

Comment: @user2652374 a "msg for normal.dot"? What you mean with that? This code is fine and releases the objects OK. The only reason explaining that the objects are not released is the code crashing before reaching this part and, if you execute this code, this sounds impossible. Can you please do a step-by-step execution and tell me what happens? Or tell your exact testing conditions (docx files you are using, if possible to show them)

Comment: i have a folder which has 2 docx documents and containing a word that i search for so i run the code it gives me 2 OK messages it means that i found them and in the end it gives me this normal.dotm was being edited by another word session. if you save this document with the original name, you will overwrite any changes made in the other sessions do you want to save the document using the original name anyway

Comment: it is searcghing an opnned file i saw the exception

Comment: @user2652374 then you haven't killed all the opened winword instances. This code does not open .dotm files. This is something on your computer. If you want to go completely safe, you might want to restart the computer. After restarting it this code should be fine. I will tell you my exact testing conditions just to make sure that you are not unadvertedly taking further issues into account...

Comment: @user2652374... on the other hand, I am not sure why you have this line oWord.NormalTemplate.Saved = True (not doing anything wrong in my computer though), what might also contributing to provoke your problem. If you want to save the file, just do oWord.ActiveDocument.Save(). Anyway... I will explain you my exact testing conditions in the next message and you can try both things (making sure that you kill all the instances and remove the savetemplate line)...

Comment: @user2652374 I open a new project put a button, a combobox and a textbox on it; (add the Word interop reference, logically) write all the code in this answer inside Private Sub search(); and associate this sub to the click event of the button. I make sure that there is no running winword instances, create a folder "1" with 2 docx files in it (each of them containing "123"), execute the program, type "123" in the textbox and click on the button. I get 2 popups saying OK. I close the program and press ctrl-alt-sup again and confirm that there is no running winword processes.

Comment: By setting the Saved property to true Word will not prompt you to save the template anymore but in my case it is.

Comment: @user2652374 I read your last message -> not sure why happens this, but this situation does not trigger an error, but a warning message and thus depending upon what you do the releasing part might not be reached

Comment: @user2652374 you can change the displayalerts property or perform further actions to account for this issue. But I don't think that this belongs to the original question "releasing Word objects". This code should work fine under most of the conditions (as described in the aforementioned test); if you have special conditions, you should account for them (or ask for further help), but this has nothing to do with a proper release of objects: if this code is properly executed, the objects should be released.

Comment: Man i did as u told me worked like a charm i made a new project and it works thank you so much you've been a great help thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Vb.net, but in F# I used

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject xlApp |> ignore
```

after ".Quit()", to end the process, but you must search, how to give the name of your word application at the place of xlApp

I will place this after the "End If" at the end.

I hope it will be helpfull for you

Comment: Thank you but i already used finalrealsecomobject didnt work after quit

Comment: I would make it at the end, after End If.

Comment: you can not make after end if coz it will not reach there it will loop through all documents first and the opened searched document will be searched and throws an error

Comment: And if you put only one more at the end, but you let the rest?

Comment: it wont reach there it will loop through all documents and once a doc is searched it will be opened